# Consulta Agrupación Condicionada Sql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

**Buenas tardes.**

Ando atorado en una consulta que es sencilla, o al menos eso creo pero ando ya un poco bloqueado.

La situación es la siguiente. En mi tabla tengo los siguientes registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que necesito hacer es que si se encuentra una marca de 'Cobrada', no me muestre absolutamente nada de ese docto; es decir que tanto la Aut SST como PROSS que tienen la marca de cobrada no me aparezca y solo aparezca como a continuación les muestro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté hacerlo con ésta consulta pero solo logro eliminar los registros que tienen la marca de 'Cobrado'.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT status,Aut,docto,fdocto,nombre,rfc,frec,imp,obs FROM t_base 
WHERE id_seq not in
(SELECT id_seq FROM t_base WHERE status in ('Cobrada','Cacelada','Cancelada','Cancelado'))
AND docto in ('2018-02030405','2019-010203','2020-010203')
ORDER BY docto DESC
GO
```

Y esta consulta me arroja lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ando ya un poco estresado por esta consulta, les pido una disculpa y espero me puedan ayudar.

**Saludos compañeros.**

Comment: osea quieres filtrar el campo `aut`, no `id_seq`? No entiendo bien por qué en tu where estas filtrando el id

Comment: @DannyTalent, lo estoy filtrando para que ese sea mi identificador, pero si, estoy revisando si en lugar de ponerlo por el id, sea por el docto. Reviso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás comparando mal. Si no quieres que aparezca ninguna fila de ese `docto` si ya está marcado como cobrado, entonces tienes que filtrar por ese campo y no por uno que cambia cada fila.

```
SELECT  status,
        Aut,
        docto,
        fdocto,
        nombre,
        rfc,
        frec,
        imp,
        obs 
FROM t_base 
WHERE docto not in(
                    SELECT docto 
                    FROM t_base 
                    WHERE status in ('Cobrada','Cacelada','Cancelada','Cancelado'))
AND docto in ('2018-02030405','2019-010203','2020-010203')
ORDER BY docto DESC;
```